# Upload 2 old Lego books

Tags: instructions, history, vintage

[image: Some I've built from my old Lego instructions and books, & 3 pages]

I've scanned 2 old Lego books of images & some instructions and can now see them better on PC. Made all animals on page 9 (in photo) apart from 1 small dog, using Lego I've had for years. Bought more & built more. Taken some apart to re-use. Don't know what the books are called, or their year, late 50's/early 60's. Who would like images of them? As I think most then better to put on a website. I've 'cut' pages of them on PC. Written notes for some. Some changes: the flag on the yacht, women's skin colour, smaller tusks on the elephants.
The lion, what = that flat thing behind his back legs? 2×4 bracket with 1×2, but then it can't be 2×4 his legs are attached to.
So books = Ideas Book N°2 & N°3, N°1 (mostly like N°2) is on the internet. Aka 238-1, 238-5 & 238-8.

Found some pages of Ideas Book N°2 on Worldbricks, including p.1 I was missing, but pdf file of all page = wrong book.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not in an answerable StackExchange format.

Comment: OP should contact BrickSet (www.brickset.com) as they have a database of all LEGO catalogs. They might not have these catalogs yet.